# Play sound based on array element using its index

Tags: android, arrays, audio

I'm fairly new to android so please forgive my ignorance or incompetence.

I am essentially trying to create an app that displays a random saying by using setText on a TextView, getting the data from an array. I then want to be able to match, and play the appropriate audio for the saying.

I would assume this is done by finding the index of the element in the array and assigning a value to match this with the audio files.

Hope that makes sense! Thanks.

This is what i have so far:

```
public class Sayings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


MediaPlayer mp;

String[] sayings = {"Saying1", "Saying2", "Saying3", "Saying4", "Saying5"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sayings);

    Button btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_button);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);

    btnRandom.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sayings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int resId = 0;

    switch  (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.random_button:
        RandomSaying();
        resId = R.raw.saying1;
        break;

    case R.id.next_button:
        NextSaying();
        break;

    case R.id.back_button:
    BackSaying();
        break;
    }

    if (mp != null) {

    mp.release();
    }

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();



    }


public void RandomSaying () {
    String randomSaying = (sayings[new Random().nextInt(sayings.length)]);

    TextView sayingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaySayings);

    sayingsTextView.setText('"' + randomSaying + '"');  

}
```

Comment: What do you obtain when you run this code ?

Comment: Currently it works fine in regards to generating the random saying. I only have it set to play the specified "Saying1" no matter what is in the TextView for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  a HashMap to store correspondance between the strings and the resource ids :

```
HashMap<String, Integer> sayingsResIds = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

//when initializing your array sayings, put the corresponding ids : 
sayingsResId.put("saying1",R.raw.saying1); // do this for all your files
// then get the resource id corresponding to your string , when choosing a random saying: 
resId = sayingsResIds.get(randomSaying);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done as you have suggested and it matches up the sound with the saying nicely. The only problem i now have is that if i press the "Random" button again it will not generate a new random. It will only do this if the app is restarted.

Comment: UPDATE: After much fiddling i managed to sort it out! Thanks a lot for your help!